# Why are POCO's a good thing in relation to EF4, nHiberate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

Why is it so important to support POCO's in EF4, Linq2SQL or any other data mapping technologies? I understand the concept of a POCO in the OO sense but is there something else I'm missing when it comes to ORM's?

EDIT: I'm just adding my personal **definition of a POCO in the context of ORM's**:
It is a class that is hand-coded by the developer as opposed to a class that is generated, augmented or annotated by a ORM mapping tool (like Visual Studio's EF4 designer).

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"POCO" means the framework places no unnecessary or counterintuitive constraints on the entity objects – no need to use a code generator, no need to extend a framework-provided base class, extensively annotate properties, or to have to, for the most part, write different code than you would were the classes always stored in-memory. This keeps the concern of persisting data outside the model classes and reduces cognitive overhead.

Compare the POCO definitions from NHibernate or EF Code First with the code Visual Studio generates for EF without Code First and ask yourself which one you prefer to read and maintain. (When poking around a new codebase for instance.)

Comment: Good point. Is there a tradeoff between doing it the decoupled/maintainable way and the quick/code generated way?

Comment: In EF-CF, you're generally expected to adhere to several mostly reasonable conventions so it works "automagically". If you require more control over things, you have to study up on the correct annotations to override these conventions. When using code generation, you're working with a visual designer, and the Properties panel will show you what you can customise at a glance instead of having to fish through the documentation and reintroduce clutter into the not-very-plain-COS-anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't want your code to depend on a certain ORM technology. POCOs minimize that dependency. It's just one incarnation of the general principle of decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

> The Entity Framework enables you to use custom data classes together
>   with your data model without making any modifications to the data
>   classes themselves.

This means that you can use "plain-old" CLR objects (POCO), such as existing domain objects, with your data model. These POCO data classes which are mapped to entities that are defined in a data model, support most of the same query, insert, update, and delete behaviors as entity types that are generated by the Entity Data Model tools.

Comment: so is it true to say EF supports POCO's?

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework supports POCOs if you use its "code first" incarnation.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Entity Framework supported POCOs before the current code first release.  I would even go so far as to say that one wouldn't get a whole lot of benefit from using EF code-first instead of EF model-first as far as POCOs are concerned.  Both are equally doable.  But if you're into RAD, forget pure POCOs altogether... they require a lot of additional work and patience in EF.